# Why can't I attach the debugger?

Tags: asp-classic, debugging, google-chrome, iis-5, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 SP1 and trying to debug a website created in ASP Classic. I have read numerous tutorials, however nothing seems to be working (PEBKAC?). I have enabled server-side debugging in IIS and am attaching the debugger to dllhost.exe. When I open my page in Google Chrome, set breakpoints and set VS to debug, nothing happens. I don't get any errors so I'm not sure what else to post.

Any ideas?

Thank you. :)

Comment: I assume you found this article??  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/DebugVBScriptVS2008.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach to either w3wp.exe or aspnet_wp.exe - depending on your OS and IIS version.

Answer (score 0):

Are you attaching to the  w3wp process in your IDE? If your IIS site is running on your local host, then this SHOULD do the trick.

Comment: That process does not seem to exist for me.

Comment: hmmm, prlby different process name in IIS5. Anyhow, the IIS process is the one you need to attach too.